# The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraint, alter-table, ddl

I need to check `datecom` is less than `datelivr`

```
create table Commande
(
Numcom int identity primary key,
Datecom date,
Datelivr date,
Codecli int foreign key references clients (Codecli) 
)

alter table Commande 
    add constraint date_check check(datediff(day,Datecom,Datelivr) > 0)
```

but I get the error message:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "date_check". The conflict occurred in database "tp4", table
>   "dbo.Commande".

How can this happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory: Your check constraint is trying to enforce that all values in `Datecom` are at least one day earlier than `Datelivr`, but you must have at least one row where this is not true - either `Datecom` is the same day, later, or one of the values is `NULL`. Find those rows using:

```
SELECT Numcom, Datecom, Datelivr
FROM dbo.Commade
WHERE datediff(day,Datecom,Datelivr) <= 0
  OR Datecom IS NULL
  OR Datelivr IS NULL;
```

Comment: On the contrary; if the error message was self-explanatory, there wouldn't be a question about it! It says the conflict is with the statement itself instead of the data in the table, which is phrased poorly. Your explanation is much clearer.

Comment: @James Not interested in semantic bingo.